# When do we need to use " try, except" in python? Is it similar to "if, else"?

Tags: python, if-statement, try-catch

```
try: 
  print(x)
except:
  print("Done!!")
```

Why do we need to use, **`try`** and **`except`**.

Can someone explain **`try`** and  **`except`** method? Could you answer with an example and explanation.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp

Comment: What have you read on the topic and what is not clear about it?

Comment: Google ‘exception handling in python’. It is rather different to an if else. Note that the code in finally always runs, which can be useful.

Comment: The vendor seems to provide information on the subject: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: Basically, they are there to catch errors. If you have some code that might result in an error, you put it in a try block and if it creates an error, the code in except gets executed instead of your program just stopping.

Comment: Please repeat [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: Ok, now it's clear to me. Thanks, to all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `try` and `except` blocks are used to catch and handle exceptions. The program will first run the `try` statement "normally". If there are any exceptions that trigger in the try statement, the except statement will trigger. For example,

```
try:
    print(str) #Here, str isn't defined and you will get an exception which triggers the except statement
except NameError: #Here, you specify which exception you think might happen
    #Do something
```

> **You can have as many exception blocks as you want!** Also note that if you catch an exception the other ones **will not** trigger. Also note that an exception block with no arguments will catch all exceptions.

The finally block can be added on and triggers even if there was an exception or not. This can be helpful for closing and cleaning objects. Another example,

```
try:
    #stuff
except:
    #stuff if exception
finally:
    #do stuff even if there is or is not an exception
```

I should also mention the `pass` function. You should use it if you want to ignore exceptions. Example,

```
try:
    #stuff
except:
    pass #i don't want to do anything
```

Hope I helped!

Answer (score 0):

Try and except are used when you want to catch an error.
Basically, it would first run the code under try. If it catches an error, it moves on and runs the code under except. Like this:

```py
try:
    print(x)
except:
    print('Could not find variable x.')
```

It will run what is under try, and if the code runs successfully it will skip the except part and continue running your program. In our case, if x is defined then it will run successfully, however if it not it will catch the error and go to except.